# Getting the error "Apache port:443 is being used by another application" after installing AMPPS

Tags: apache, wamp

After installing AMPPS for Windows, while trying to launch Apache I get an error saying,

> Apache port:443 is being used by another application.

I do not have any other programs (that I know of) such as Skype that are currently running. How can I monitor my 443 port or change the port for Apache?

By the way, I have McAfee as an anti-virus.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open command prompt(start -> run -> cmd) and type the following command :

```
C:\> netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:443
```

Last column of the output is the PID of the application using port 443.

You can find the application name in Task Manager. Go to Process Tab then in Menu Bar of Task Manager go to View -> Select Column -> Check "PID" and press Ok. Search for the PID in the list(Click Below "Show processes from all users" in case if you don't find the PID), corresponding process is the application which is using port 443. Stop or Uninstall it to make your AMPPS Apache work.

Comment: Thank you! It was my VMware Workstation that was using the port. Now I just need to find out how to change that port, if possible.

Comment: I agree with @Jigar. Sometimes Task Manager doesn't contain the PID that I am looking for, so I use process explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx , it sometimes shows processes that task manager seems to leave out.

Comment: I run on ubuntu and my /opt/lampp/xampp start was giving me the same error of showing that the port isnt free so i did `netstat -tanpl|grep 443` and the last line was `tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      - ` So the last didn't contain the pid, how do i sort this out ??

Answer (score 3):

For terminate any process:

1. open cmd as administrator
2. `netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:443`
3. shows: `TCP 0.0.0.0:443 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4876`, NOTE THE PID 4876
4. `taskkill /pid 4876 /f`

For disable port of other program(vmware):

1. open VMware Workstation
2. Edit->Preferences...->Shared VMs->Change Settings->Yes->Disable Sharing
3. You can change the port. -> Ok

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue as on port 443, vmware service was running, i went to task manager and stopped the service and then started apache and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

After getting the `pid` number using `netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:443`, if you are having trouble finding `pid 443` in Task Manager then:

Kill the process 443 by using the cmd: `taskkill /pid 443`.

You will avoid downloading any software or any other headache.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the more elaborated way to solve this issue based on comments from Jigar and Daniel Dropik(Thank You guys),
So check with which service you are getting this port issue, in my case it was with Apache and MySQL.

Starting with Apache, either click on "Logs" in XAMPP control panel and open error log to see the problem or go to XAMPP installation directory and run "apache_start.bat" batch file, this will also give to the problem cause.

Now you have got the Port number which causing trouble,
Now follow Jigar's comment and run

```
netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:443
```

Remember 443 is the port number so enter the port number causing the issue.
This command will give the PID of the process using the port like below,

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4996
```

So 4996 is the process ID(PID) that you want to stop.

Now using Task Manager you could see and kill the process but some processes could not displayed by Task Manager, in this case you have to download Mycrosoft's [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), unzip the downloaded package and run the ".exe" file as an Administrator.

You will find a bunch of processes running, sort them using PIDs and you will find your service.

Select that service and stop it.

Then go to the XAMPP control panel and run Apache and you will be able to start it this time.

Follow same process for MySQL as well.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

First off you must find the process using that port. we can find it with below command.

```
netstat -aon | findstr 443
```

then we might finish finded process either below command:

```
taskkill /PID PORTNUMBER /F
```

OR

you can go to taskmanager and find the process from process bar ( with swiching PID column) and click on end task.

Answer (score 0):

- go to `Ampps\apache\conf\extra`
- open file `httpd-ssl.conf` with note++
- change the port

Listen 443--->change port

VirtualHost default:443--->"change port **>
DocumentRoot "D:/Ampps/www"
ServerName localhost:443--->**change port

and saved

Comment: Please provide more instruction.